# Multiple JTextField clearing

Tags: java

In my program I have 50+ text fields and have a clear button for them. I was wondering if there is a way to loop through them all to clear them rather than setting each text field to textfield.setText(""). I know that this way works but am just wondering what else is possible.

Thanks

Comment: Create a `List<JTextField>` and iterate through it.

Comment: Add all the `JtextField` in a list then iterate through the list and clear the value.

Answer (score 1):

Create list with all text field and just clear them all:

```
List<JTextField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
fields.add(new JTextField());
fields.add(new JTextField());
fields.add(new JTextField());

fields.forEach((a) -> a.setText(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the whole frame to the function and then fetch all components within this frame and check if it is a textfield just clear i

Class with static function:

```
public class JCTest
{
    public static void Clear(JInternalFrame intFrame)
    {
        if (intFrame == null)
            return;
        Container con = intFrame.getContentPane();
        for (Component c : con.getComponents())
        {
            if (c instanceof JTextField)
            {
                JTextField j = (JTextField)c;
                j.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call it:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JInternalFrame intFrame = new JInternalFrame();
        JCTest.Clear(intFrame);
    }
}
```

Or just do it inside the view class

```
for (Component C : this.getComponents())
{    
    if (C instanceof JTextField ){

        ((JTextField) C).setText(""); 
    }
}
```